# Deploying applications from Eclipse to OAS (OC4J)

Tags: eclipse, deployment, oc4j, jdeveloper, oas

We were using JDev to develop our applications and deploy them to OC4J and OAS.
we used to use JDev to create the data-source configuration for us both on dev and on deployment. (on dev using the wizard that come with jdev to connect to data-source.. and on deployment hence we don't  need to do any Data-source configurations on the app server manually)

But, when we moved to eclipse, we couldn't no longer be able to deploy the EAR file unless we create the data-source manually (either using the `em` or `j2ee\home\config\data-sources.xml` but on some deployment, we may not be able to do such thing.

So, can we add some files for example to the EAR so that we can tell OAS that we need from it to create the DS for us?? 
Hint (I am hearing about some thing named orion*.xml, is this related to that request??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can.

You need to place the correct data-sources.xml into your EAR/META-INF and reference it from your EAR/META-INF/orion-application.xml the same way as j2ee\home\config\data-sources.xml is referenced from j2ee\home\config\application.xml